# Hot Swapped Hard Drives in Windows, Now Windows Reports the Drive as RAW

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, partition-recovery

I have a quick release hard drive bay in my W10 PC so I can easily swap hard drives. When swapping them out, Windows will never seem to recognize the new replacement hdd. I have to open Computer Management and rescan the drives, then it will show the correct hdd in File Explorer. If I don't rescan the drives, File Explorer will still show the *previous drive* as still connected and using the same drive letter. Apparently, Windows keeps a cache of the old drive partition or directory, because if you accidentally open the drive (which I did, accidentally of course), it still shows the files and folders from the previous drive. So, I thought I would try to open a file just to see what it would do. As expected, since the files are actually on the previous disconnected drive, it popped up an error that the file is missing or corrupted. Though surprisingly, it opened text files without issue. Also, I could only go about 2 subfolders deep before it would error out again. Guessing I was hitting the limit of the cache reserved for the file directory.

So, after realizing the issue, I rescanned the drives under Computer Management. To my horror, it showed my 2 TB hdd as RAW! *(F:) 1863.01 GB RAW Healthy (Primary Partition)*

This drive was working perfectly 20 minutes earlier before I temporarily swapped it out with a 500 GB drive to transfer some files. The 500 GB drive only had a few files totaling ~200MB, so not even half a GB, so if it wrote over anything, it shouldn't have been much.

Knowing this drive is in great shape, and this sudden change from NTFS to RAW, which likely resulted by me trying to access the drive while Windows still thought the previous drive was connected, what are my chances of fixing this? Has anyone experienced this issue before with hot swapping a drive, and accidentally accessing the drive before Windows rescans and actually shows the correct drive in File Explorer? I have around 1.2 TB of data on this drive I would rather not lose.

I created an image of the 2 TB drive, and it finished this morning (14 hours later). R-Studio shows the one partition as *Partition1 Data NTFS 1MB 1.82 TB*. Though, when I open Partition1, it shows the directory from the previous 500 GB drive (which remember, only had a few small files totaling ~200 MB). Obviously, Windows somehow wrote the 500 GB directory structure to the 2 TB drive. If it updated the partition, shouldn't it have also changed the 2 TB size to the same size as the 500 GB drive?

Comment: Perhaps you should eject the drive before unplugging it?

Comment: As @ChanganAuto said… just because the drive is hot-swap doesn't mean the OS is. Never physically eject a drive without putting it away first. You can do the same with an SD or USB stick - it doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: There is no eject option for a fixed drive. How am I suppose to correctly eject it when Windows does not give the option to? I always feel uneasy when I swap drives using this quick-release bay, b/c I feel like Windows is not recognizing the swap. So, I guess going forward I will shutdown the PC, then swap, though not as quick, but at least safer. Unless someone has a better alternative

Comment: idk how you do it for Windows, but on Mac you can mark drives [at system-level] as removable or non-removable. [It does its best to guess, but you can override it.]

Answer (score 2):

NTFS filesystems have a structure called Master File Table - MFT. In contains entries for all files on the filesystem. In addition, small files are stored directly in the MFT rather than externally to improve the performance. It looks like Windows is keeping a cached copy of the MFT in memory ([it seems to be a normal thing](https://serverfault.com/q/797736)). That's why you can browse the directory tree and open small files without the disk being present.

But Windows thinks it is present, which tells us that you don't use the safe removal feature (the same thing you should use when disconnecting USB drives). That feature makes sure that everything that's in RAM, but not yet on the drive, is flushed to the drive and no more writes are allowed. You may already see where this is going.

Windows is convinced that the drive is still there and not only readable, but also writable. It does not realize it's not the same filesystem and that it's overwriting something.

Now you have a mix of two fielsystems: a 2TB one and a 500GB one, both on one partition (yes, some filesystems have size independent from partition size). Some files may still be there, but you'll need file carving software to recover them. It may not be completely possible.

Lessons to learn:

- If something is behaving in unexpected ways, be careful.
- Use throwaway stuff for experiments.
- Backups are a necessity. Hardware and software fails, people make mistakes, you can't control everything.
- Keeping backups is cheaper and less stressful than data recovery.